# c++ reprint text in terminal with carriage return

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I would like to print an updated number in the Linux terminal, but nothing like

```
picture 1
picture 2
picture 3 
picture [...]
```

I already know how to do it with C code

```
printf("\rpicture %d", i);
fflush(stdout);
```

where `i` is my picture number

My question is : Is it possible to do it with `std::cout` or something even simple like that instead of `printf` ?

EDIT :

Using `std::cout << "\rPicture " << i << "done";` wasn't as good as `printf` because I didn't see all number scroll in the terminal

```
Picture 74 done

Picture 150 done
FPS          : 7.89474
picture number   : 150
```

P.S : we aren't here to critize my FPS number, that's my program which isn't optimize at all

Comment: `printf("\rpicture %d", i);` ---> `std::cout << "\rpicture " << i;`

Comment: I don't think about that, but after trying it, it didn't work as well as the printf example; I'll updated now my post with result

Comment: `because I didn't see all number scroll in the terminal` If you want to see all the numbers why do you use `\r`? It's a bit unclear what you want to do.

Comment: @DimChtz with the printf command, I see all number scrolled at the same place, but with the std::cout command, that didn't work as good as printf; I just see the '74' and the last one, '150' as if it was very slower than the printf display

Comment: Maybe need to flush the buffer:  `std::cout << "\rpicture " << i << std::flush;`

Comment: works fine now, make a mistake in rewriting it (fflush instead of flush)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, it is as simple as in C and I didn't think about it at 1rst time

In C :

```
printf("\rPicture : %d", i);
fflush(stdout);
```

In C++ :

```
std::cout << "\rPicture " << i << std::flush;
```